# Fetching data from backend causes infinite loop and never successfully loads

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

This is probably my inexperience with Async functions showing here but i'm having an issue where my code to fetch templates from a back-end into react simply repeats without properly setting the state to the data

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import './main.css';
import Frame from './Components/Frame';


function App() {
    const [view, setView] = useState(window.location.pathname);

    console.log('logging view ' + view);

    return (
        <div className="App container m-4">
            <Frame viewF={'nav'} />
            <div id='content'>
                <Frame viewF={view} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

main component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function createMarkup(markup) {
    return { __html: markup };
}

const Frame = (props) => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const contactBackend = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/' + props.viewF, {
                'methods': 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            //const data = response.json(); //alternate approach
            //console.log(data);
            setContent(response.json());

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    contactBackend();

    return (
        <div className="m-2" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(content)}>

        </div>
    )

};

export default Frame;
```

The backend can send data, it worked in an earlier and simpler version. I can also see the returned values with some console logs. but the most it ever puts into the returned div is [object Promise] and then it sends 1000s of requests until the back-end crashes

Comment: `contentBackend()` is asynchronous, so when you call it, it starts running, and `Frame` immediately returns the JSX, with `content` being an empty string. Look into `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is unconditionally calling `contactBackend` in the function body, and the result is an enqueued state update which triggers a component rerender. This is an unintentional side-effect.

Typically this is called in an `useEffect` hook when mounting.

`response.json()` also returns a Promise, so you also want to wait for that to resolve.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const contactBackend = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/' + props.viewF, 
        {
          'methods': 'GET',
          headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }

      const content = await response.json();
      setContent(content);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  contactBackend();
}, []); // <-- empty dependency to run once after initial render
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I assumed that have two await expressions was a no go from the previous errors but that was likely the lack of useEffect. lifesaver!